# PHP suppress warning with the @ character not working on command line

Tags: php

I have an external include file in my php script which triggers a Warning when executing it in the browser. So I put an @ character before it and very nice, now the Warning doesn't happen anymore. My problem is that if I now execute the script on the CLI the warning is not suppressed. How can I also suppress the warning for CLI?

This is a new VPS running PHP 7.3.

```
@include_once('externalsourcefile.php');
```

Result is:

> WARNING : ""continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?" at line xx (externalsourcefile.php)

**UPDATE**: the point is that die include file is an external source, which I can't edit to resolve the Warning by my own.

Comment: personally I'd remove the `@` - it's use is null, why would you want to suppress errors in dev?

Comment: "_wich triggers a Warning when executing it in the browser._" Resolve of the warning instead of hiding it

Comment: Why not fix the issue at line 2? :-D

Comment: `@` suppresses the warning on that particular function call, not the subsequent ones (so in your example, only on `include_once`, not whats within that file). That said, usage of the suppressing operator is ***really not recommended*** - always fix your errors and handle them properly, or it'll bite you in the butt one day.

Comment: Not a good practice to use @ warning suppression! my suggestion is that you should rewite include code

Comment: I edited the description, the point is that the include files is a external source...

Comment: what do you mean by External? is it from some other server ?

Comment: @Mangesh Sathe its a pear file...

Comment: @RiggsFolly but why does this works for the browser?

Comment: one simple question, Why do you want to include a file which is not there? And if it is there the why to use Warning suppression like @.

Comment: @MangeshSathe the file is there, but its an external source (from a pear package), so I cant edit it, to solve the warning...

Comment: @MangeshSathe, and please comment on [my comment-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59214824/385571) below

Answer (score 0):

You must refer to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php#84108 , It will give you an idea how include_once works. You must remove @ soon as possible, bad practice!

```
if(include_once('externalsourcefile.php') == false) {
} else {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@` suppresses warnings for that statement, in your case the actual `include_once`, not the stuff that happens inside it.

*I'm writing this as an answer, because it is too long to put in a comment. Saying that `@` should **never** be used is wrong. It's using it **without thinking** that is wrong.*

Consider this simple code being run in a busy multi-process environment:

```
clearstatcache(true, $pathname);
if(is_dir($pathname) && $dh=opendir($pathname)) {
   // readdir() loop here
}else{
   // error handling here
}
```

This code has a **race condition**. It has happened for me numerous times that the directory has disappeared between the `is_dir()` return and the `opendir()` call, leading to warnings on the console:

```
PHP Warning:  opendir(/the/path/in/use): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /path/to/script.php on line 2
```

So how could this race be worked around without disabling warnings from `opendir()`, I ask you?

Disabling globally is *IMHO* worse than doing it on specific statements like the `opendir()` call above.

Comment: @Qirel, any comments on this?

Answer (score 0):

As already said, the error is not caused by the `include_once` statement itself but by the code running inside the included file (you can determine that by reading carefully the error message).

It *should* work, anyway. There must be something else going on.

I can think of three possibilities:

1. The CLI interpreter in your VPS is configured to use a [custom error handler](https://php.net/set_error_handler) that doesn't support the [error suppression operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php):

   > the standard PHP error handler is completely bypassed for the error types specified by error_types unless the callback function returns `FALSE`. `error_reporting()` settings will have no effect and your error handler will be called regardless - however **you are still able to read the current value of `error_reporting`** and act appropriately. Of particular note is that **this value will be 0 if the statement that caused the error was prepended by the @ error-control operator.**
2. The interpreter is configured for debugging and Xdebug has been set up with the [`xdebug.scream` directive](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#scream):

   > If this setting is 1, then Xdebug will disable the @ (shut-up) operator so that notices, warnings and errors are no longer hidden.
3. The browser interpreter is running an earlier PHP version then the CLI one. The [*"continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break"* warning](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.incompatible.php#migration73.incompatible.core.continue-targeting-switch) is a backwards-incompatible change in PHP/7.3. It didn't trigger a warning before.

In either case, and as also already noted, the question itself illustrates that suppressing errors can lead to hard-to-diagnose bugs.